# Sympy e**x Derivative Malfunction?

Tags: python, sympy

So I'm new to the whole coding thing, I only use python to do my math homework and I'm looking over some old code that used to run perfectly fine, but now there's a weird problem with sympy's derivative function.

I run the basic code:

```
func = e**x
deriv = sp.diff(func, x)
print(deriv)
```

And it returns:

```
1.0*2.71828182845905**x
```

instead of `e**x`.

Any ideas of what's wrong? Or am I missing a module that I should install?

Update:
Woooow, that's so embarassing lol I figured it out while I was typing this up. You're supposed to use `exp(x)` rather than `e**x`! I guess I'll post it anyway just in case someone has the same issue and they come across this.

Comment: You should post the solution as an answer instead of an edit to your question. It is perfectly alright to answer your own questions.

Comment: Note that `2.71828182845905` is the value of `e` rounded to a few decimal places. So your original code is correct.

Comment: How did you declare or import `e`?  Note that the Euler constant in sympy is `E` or `exp(1)`.  As you are getting imprecise float values as output, you probably initalized `e=2.718281828459`.  In sympy it is highly recommended avoiding floats as much as possible. Also, instead of `E**x`, you can use `exp(x)`